# Unsplit two arrays Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have the following code

```js
var Louis = [ 'Louis.IX', 'Louis.VIII' ]
var array1 = []; 
var array2 = [];

for (var i = 0; i < Louis.length; i++) {
    var split = Louis[i].split(".");  
    array1.push(split[0]); // before the dot
    array2.push(split[1]); // after the dot
}
console.log("Louisname", array1);
console.log("Louisnum", array2);
```

and the output is
Louisname [ 'Louis', 'Louis' ]
Louisnum [ 'IX', 'VIII' ]

Now any idea on how can i revert the output into the initial array? Please help me, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) with its second index argument to join elements in the first array with the second array by returning a string which contains elements in both arrays like so:

```js
const array1 = ["Louis", "Louis"];
const array2 = ["IX","VIII"];

const original = array1.map((v, i) => `${v}.${array2[i]}`);
console.log(original);
```

If you're new to JS, here is a more straightforward/imperative way of achieving the same result (see code comments for details):

```js
const array1 = ["Louis", "Louis"];
const array2 = ["IX","VIII"];

const original = [];
for(let i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) { // loop through all elements in array 1
  const original_str = array1[i] + "." + array2[i]; // join array element `i` in array1 with array element `i` in array2
  original.push(original_str); // add the joined string to the `original` array
}
console.log(original);
```

Comment: Thanks Nick, i think this is the answer i'm looking for. I appreciate it, That was helpful.

Comment: @CodingBaby no worries, I added an additional answer which you might find easier to understand